# Javascript how to initiate an event upon click on array elements displayed as buttons

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick

I am populating an array with given items and displaying them as buttons. The user shall click on one of the buttons. Depending on the button he clicks on the answer may be different. This is what I did so far:

```js
var1 = "1";
var2 = "2";
var3 = "3";
var4 = "4";
var myarray=[var1,var2,var3,var4]; 

for(var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++)
{
    document.write("<div>");
    {
       document.write("<input type='button' value='" + myarray[i] + "'/>");
    }
    document.write("</div>");
}

//add click handler with check answer
var checkAnswer = document.querySelector('input[type=object]');
var value = checkAnswer.value;
var btn = document.querySelector('input[type=object][value=Check]');

btn.onclick = function () {
    value = checkAnswer.value;
    if (value == var4) {
       display.innerHTML = "good answer";
    } 
 else {
  display.innerHTML = "wrong answer";
    return false;
}};
```

Any idea how that works?

Comment: `input[type=object]`? Also, create a element using `document.createElement`

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    (function(val) {
        btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.data = val;     // assign the value to compare to an attribute on the button.
        btn.innerHTML = 'option'  + val;
        btn.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
    })(arr[i]);  // create a closure, so that all buttons don't refer to the same value later.
}

function checkAnswer(evt) {
    if (evt.target.data == 4) {  // evt.target == button
        alert('Good answer');
    } else {
        alert('Bad answer');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, bugs-cena. That is exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm.

Comment: Another question. How can I add a space between the elements? If I write `btn.innerHTML = "<br>" + val";` it will only make the button bigger. What is the correct syntax to add html code?

Comment: You need to use CSS to do that.
<style>button {display: inline-block; margin: 10px; padding: 5px;} </style>

Comment: @user9 can you accept the answer, if it works for you?